# Dynamic label with number of points in scatterplot based on transform selection in Altair?

Tags: python, altair

**tl;dr**: is there a way to get a dynamic count of points in filtered plots in Altair?

---

In the ['filtering by selection'](https://altair-viz.github.io/altair-tutorial/notebooks/06-Selections.html#filtering-by-selection) example for Altair, it is possible to update a scatterplot based on a selection in a linked bar chart.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars()

click = alt.selection_point(encodings=['color'])

scatter = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color='Origin:N'
).transform_filter(
    click
)

hist = alt.Chart(cars).mark_bar().encode(
    x='count()',
    y='Origin',
    color=alt.condition(click, 'Origin', alt.value('lightgray'))
).add_params(
    click
)

scatter & hist
```

[image: unfiltered charts]

[image: filtered charts]

However, it would be useful to show how many data points remain in the scatterplot after filtering. How can this be achieved?

It is possible to get a *static* count of data in a dataframe and use that for a label, which I tried with another approach eg:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = pd.DataFrame({'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]})
total_count = data['values'].sum()

# Create data frame for total count
count_data = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['Total Count'], 'count': [total_count]})

# Combine data
combined_data = pd.concat([data, count_data])

# Create histogram with text for total count
hist = alt.Chart(combined_data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='values:Q',
    y='count()',
)

text = hist.mark_text(
    color='black',
    baseline='middle'
).encode(
    x=alt.value(200),  # Adjust position as needed
    y=alt.value(40),
    text='count:Q',
)

# Display the chart
hist + text
```

This adds a rather ugly label:

[image: labelled chart]

**Is there a way to append a dynamic label with the number of points present in the filtered scatterplot?** An external element would be fine, but I am quite new to Altair and haven't figured that bit out yet despite some searching.

Answer (score 0):

### To show a dynamic count of filtered data in Altair, use `transform_aggregate`

Showing how many data points are present on a plot after filtering can be done with a combination of [`transform_aggregate`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/aggregate.html) to retrive a `count`, and [text marks](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/text.html#user-guide-text-marks).

The aggregate transformation can be added on to the the plot which is getting filtered, eg: `filtered_plot.transform_aggregate(count='count(*)')`. The Text mark can then be applied as you would any label.

#### Example using iris sepal data

*Note: adding the text with count adds an 'undefined' field in the legend, which I have yet to find a way to remove*

[image: filtering with count]

Code:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data  # Example dataset library

# Sample data - iris sepal length
source = data('iris')

# Create the scatterplot - eg length by width, coloured by species
scatterplot = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='sepalLength:Q',
    y='sepalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
)

# Create a selection to filter points
selection = alt.selection_point(encodings=['color'], resolve='global')

# count 
countplot = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    y='species:N',
    x='count()',
    color=alt.condition(selection, 'species:N', alt.ColorValue('gray'))
).add_params(selection)


# Filter scatterplot based on selection
filtered_scatterplot = scatterplot.transform_filter(selection)

# Calculate count of filtered points
filtered_count = filtered_scatterplot.transform_aggregate(
    count='count(*)')

# Display count as text
text = filtered_count.mark_text(
    color='black',
    fontSize=14,
    baseline='middle'
).encode(
    x=alt.value(100),  # Adjust position as needed
    y=alt.value(10),
    text='count:Q',
)

# Display the chart with linked selection and count
filtered_scatterplot & text & countplot
```

Comment: You should be able to get the same effect using `count()` directly in the encoding as with a separate `transform_aggregate`

Comment: @joelostblom is that in the encoding for the label? ie something like `mark_text(..).encode(text='count()')` ?

Comment: Yes, where you currently use `text=count:Q`.

Comment: @joelostblom Thanks- I did try that after you suggested it, but it returned `1` in the label regardless of selection

Comment: Odd, but there seems to be some issue with the code above; when I used it, it is alwasys showing `50` no matter the selection. You can see an example of what I mean by taking https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/selection_layer_bar_month.html and then replacing the line variable with `line = alt.Chart().mark_text().encode(text='count()').transform_filter(brush)`

Comment: @joelostblom It's possible something got lost in translation between my code and SO- when I get a chance I'll have another look at the code in the A and perhaps simplifying the Q to help it be better-received -- I think this is a relatively useful thing to be able to do but a new user (like me!) would find it tricky to find out how to do :)